# Will quitting job delay US naturalization results?

Tags: usa, citizenship

A person quits their job shortly before the naturalization interview. They tell this to the immigration official in the interview (as the n-400 listed their previous job). I understand this will not affect the process result. But can it delay it, such that instead of getting immediate answer if the candidate passed the interview, the officer will take more time to investigate this (e.g. verify leaving the job was not due to something illegal etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Your employment status has no bearing on your naturalization eligibility. So no, the fact that you changed employment will not make any difference. Or rather, *should* not.

That said, any change in your information from what was originally provided on N400 may trigger a re-evaluation and re-validation, which in turn may delay the process. Whether just quitting a job would do that is hard to say with certainty, but would be unlikely.